# How can I show that a random walk is not covariance stationary?

Tags: time-series, self-study, stochastic-processes, stationarity

How can I show that a random walk ($y$ follows a random walk) is not covariance stationary? I tried to work on the formula below (with no results) Could you give me just a hint on how to proceed please?

$$Cov(y_{t+h},y_t)=E(y_{t+h}\times y_t)-E(y_t)E(y_{t+h})$$

Is this approach right?

Important: $\epsilon_t$, the shock, is an iid sequence with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2_\epsilon$.

---

If $y$ follows a RW we have
$$y_t=y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$$

then,

$$Var(y_t)=Var(y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t)=Var(y_{t-1})+\sigma_\epsilon+2Cov(\epsilon_t,y_{t-1})$$
Now I see that the variance of $y_t$ depends on the variance of $y_{t-1}$. This should suggest me that we lack covariance stationarity.

Comment: For example I know that $E(y_t)=y_{t-1}$, and also I know that its variance increases with time.

Comment: No, you know an exact expression for $y_t$, not its expectation. It's written in your question. Replace $y_t$ with something else in the covariance, the same way you did when you worked out the variance.

Comment: Incidentally, as a routine bookwork-type question, you should add the `self-study` tag and read its [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Now I see that $\text{Cov}(y_t,y_{t-1})=\text{Var}(y_{t-1})$ using the exact expression for $y_t$. In addition, I can argue that $\text{Cov}(y_s,y_{s-1})\neq \text{Cov}(y_t,y_{t-1})$ if $s\neq t$ because the $\text{Var}(y_{t-1})$ varies with time. If $y_0$ is not random, $\text{Var}(y_t)=t \sigma^2_\epsilon$. Am I right? Thank you for your help.

Comment: That's pretty close, but perhaps not quite solid. Try letting $s<t$ (without loss of generality) and think about $\text{Cov}(y_t,y_{t-1})- \text{Cov}(y_s,y_{s-1})$. Can you show it's necessarily positive?

Comment: @Glen_b If I proceed, following your hint, I obtain that $\text{Cov}(y_t,y_{t-1})- \text{Cov}(y_s,y_{s-1})=\sigma^2_\epsilon(t-s)$. Therefore, with $s<t$ the difference in the covariances depends on $(t-s)$. This is why a RW is not covariance stationary.

Comment: The point was to get to something like ... *since $\sigma^2_\epsilon (t-s) >0$, $\text{Cov}(y_t,y_{t-1})> \text{Cov}(y_s,y_{s-1})$, ...*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're making life hard for yourself there. 
You just need to use a few elementary properties of variances and covariances.

Here's one approach:

- start with the algebraic definition of your random walk process.
- derive $\text{Var}(y_t)$ in terms of $\text{Var}(y_{t-1})$ and the variance of the error term
- show that $\text{Cov}(y_t,y_{t-1}) = Var(y_{t-1})$
- argue that $\text{Cov}(y_s,y_{s-1})\neq \text{Cov}(y_t,y_{t-1})$ if $s\neq t$.

... though, frankly, I think even just going to the second step (writing $\text{Var}(y_t)$ in terms of $\text{Var}(y_{t-1})$ and the variance of the error term) is sufficient to establish it's not covariance stationary.

Comment: Thank you. Since the $\epsilon$ is iid, its covariance with $y_{t-1}$ is zero right? How can I show that the $Cov(y_t,y_{t-1})=Var(y_{t-1})$?

Answer (score 14):

For each integer $t$, $Y_t = \sum_{i=1}^t X_i$ where the $X_i$ are iid random
variables. From the independence of the $X_i$, it follows that $\operatorname{var}(Y_t) = \sum_{i=1}^t \operatorname{var}(X_i) = t\sigma^2$. For integer $h$, let 
$W = \sum_{i=t+1}^{t+h} X_i$ and note that $W$ and $Y_t$ are independent 
random variables because they are functions (sums) of disjoint collections
of independent random variables.  Then,
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{cov}(Y_{t+h},Y_t) &= \operatorname{cov}(Y_t+W,Y_t)\\
&= \operatorname{cov}(Y_t,Y_t) + \operatorname{cov}(W,Y_t)
&{\scriptstyle\text{this step follows because the covariance operator is bilinear;}}\\
&= \operatorname{var}(Y_t) + 0 &\scriptstyle{\text{0 because
independent RVs}~W~\text{and}~Y_t~\text{have zero covariance;}}\\
&= \operatorname{var}(Y_t)\\
&= t\sigma^2
\end{align}$$
and thus the covariance increases as a function of $t$ 
but is not a function of $h$ at all as is needed for covariance
stationarity.  More generally, you can show that
$\operatorname{cov}(Y_t, Y_s) = \operatorname{var}\left(Y_{\min\{t,s\}}\right)$.

Comment: Thank you Prof... Where can I find the proof or at least some explanation about the fact that $\operatorname{cov}(Y_t+W,Y_t)=\operatorname{cov}(Y_t,Y_t) + \operatorname{cov}(W,Y_t)$ if $W$ and $Y$ are independent? And why do you say that they are independent?

Comment: @Charlie $\operatorname{cov}(Y_t+W,Y_t)=\operatorname{cov}(Y_t,Y_t) + \operatorname{cov}(W,Y_t)$ **does not** require independence: it is a property of covariance that holds generally.  $W$ and $Y_t$ are independent because they are sums of two _mutually exclusive_ sets of independent random variables. Generally, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, so are $g(X)$ and $h(Y)$ for _any_ (measurable) functions $g(\cdot)$ and $h(\cdot)$. If you do not already know these concepts. you are way in over your head when you look at covariance stationarity and random walks.

Comment: This is clean and clear (+1).  For the demonstration to be logically complete you need to show (or at least assert the obvious fact) that the variance of $Y_t$ actually does change with $t$.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the upvote. It occurs to me that even the requirement for _identical_ distribution of the $X_i$ is not needed to prove that the random walk is not covariance stationary. Independence and nonzero variance (or at least one $X_i$ having nonzero variance) might suffice.  But at that point we are somewhat far from the usual meaning of random walk.

Answer (score 6):

A usual way that we show this is by writing the random walk as

$$y_t = \sum_{i=1}^tu_t$$
and so

$$\operatorname{Var}(y_t) = \operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^tu_i\right) = t\sigma^2$$

and

$$\operatorname{Cov}(y_t, y_{t+k})= E\left(\sum_{i=1}^tu_i\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{t+k}u_i\right)-E\left(\sum_{i=1}^tu_i\right)E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{t+k}u_i\right)$$

$$=E\left(\sum_{i=1}^tu_i\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{t}u_i+ \sum_{i=t+1}^{t+k}u_i\right) -E\left(\sum_{i=1}^tu_i\right)E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{t}u_i+ \sum_{i=t+1}^{t+k}u_i\right)$$

$$=E\left(\sum_{i=1}^tu_i\right)^2 - \left[E\left(\sum_{i=1}^tu_i\right) \right]^2 +E\left(\sum_{i=1}^tu_i\right)\left(\sum_{i=t+1}^{t+k}u_i\right) -E\left(\sum_{i=1}^tu_i\right)E\left(\sum_{i=t+1}^{t+k}u_i\right)$$

$$=\operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^tu_i\right) + \operatorname{Cov}\left(\sum_{i=1}^tu_i, \sum_{i=t+1}^{t+k}u_i\right)$$

The two sums in the covariance term are independent since the white noises in the first do not appear in the second (different time-indices), so this covariance is zero, and we are left with

$$\operatorname{Cov}(y_t, y_{t+k}) = \operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^tu_i\right)=t\sigma^2$$

Comment: Are you assuming that $E[u_i] = 0$ and so the result is applicable only to random walks without "drift"? I believe the result is true even when $E[u_i]\neq 0$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate It is not I that I assume it - the assumption $E[u_i]=0$ is part of the question, so my answer was given with respect to that. Of course it holds for a non zero-mean, and in fact it will be exactly the same, since shifting the distribution does not affect variance/covariance.

Comment: Yes, I know that the assumption $E[u_i]=0$ is part of the question, and also that the result is true without the assumption of zero mean. But, _your_ proof above _does_ require the mean to be zero. Yes, your proof can be easily fixed to take into account nonzero means, and maybe you will re-write your proof when you have the time, but as it stands right now, it does need the mean to be $0$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Well, I believe it is obvious, but let's trust your experience. I just generalized it.